# Olympiad Geometry question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> An isosceles triangle ABC has a right angle at A. Points E and F lie on
> sides AB and AC, respectively, such that $\angle ECB = 30^\circ$ and $\angle FBC = 15^\circ$. Lines CE and BF intersect at P and AP extended meets BC at D.
>
> Prove that DF is perpendicular to BC.

I did angle chasing and found some angles but I wasn't able to prove that DF is perpendicular to.Should I use a construction or something to prove this?

Comment: Pls add a diagram and be more specific on what you tried. Simple angle chasing will not lead to the answer.

Comment: Drop altitude $EG$ on $BP$ and altitude $EH$ on $BC$. Let $EP=x$, then $EG=...$, $EB=...$, $EH=...$, $CE=...$. Then you can find $\angle PAC$. And then last step, which I don't want to spoil.

Comment: AP is perpendicular to  BC not FP. Draw the figure you will find why.

Answer (score 1):

**Cookbook for a solution**

This Problem can be solve with [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem). With the given angels we get $\frac {AE}{AC}=\tan 15^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$ and $\frac {AF}{AB}=\tan 30^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. These values can be used to calculate $\frac{BD}{CD}$. Using $\frac{BC}{AC}=\sqrt{2}$ we can now calculate $\frac{CF}{CD}$. This should give $\sqrt{2}$ and proves that $CDF$ has a right angle at $D$.

Remark: If we assume $AB=AC=1$ (or $BC=1$) the indicated calculations are a little easier. This is a personal preference.